# Is it true the Michio Kaku has completed a unified field theory started by Einstein by making use of string theory?

Tags: string-theory, unified-theories, string-field-theory

This professor has a few documentaries available explaining science to the layman like myself and he showed an equation no longer then a sentence that he says unifies all the know forces and particles in the universe.  How can this be possible?

Maybe I should add a thought or two for clarity.  How was it decided that a "new" force was needed for radioactive decay ?  And finally below:

Then I assume it was shown that that weak force and electromagnetism were actually the same underlying "entity" at some earlier time in our universe. Assuming then that gravity and the strong force along with the electroweak force are unified then wouldn't the theory have to necessarily show that either no other fundamental force can exist or show the total of the ones that can exist?

Comment: I wonder do you have a copy of the equation. My guess it is what is called a Langrangian, for which all the known forces, except gravity, can be derived. So it most likely not a unified theory of anything but people better qualified than I may confirm this for you. If you use Wikipedia and search for Standard Model, you may see what Kaku intended to convey.

Comment: Sorry , did not know it was a duplicate.  Interesting !  The second question is of more interest , what criteria are needed to determine a force fundamental and the third question even more interesting if an equation can unify all the fundamental forces would it not be a necessary condition for the equation to show there can be no others?  Is there a Godel theorem equivalent to particles . :-)